# Java оператор "if"

Tags: java, if

Написал данный код и он как-то некорректно работает.

```
if (years == 0 ){
        age = ""; }
    if (years == 1 ){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=4){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years <=20){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years ==21){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=24){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years <=30){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years ==31){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=34){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years <=40){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years ==41){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=44){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years <=50){
        age = "лет"; }
```

При любом возрасте пишет "лет"

Comment: Так у вас последнему условию years <=50 соответствуют все возрасты)) Вот переменная и получает значение "лет".

Comment: Я тоже над этим думал, и как это исправить, пробовал с else но ничего не вышло

Comment: Не в ручную же писать каждую единицу?

Comment: Как на счет того, чтобы сделать все команды строго наоборот?

Comment: Я думаю, что лучше использовать switch / case.

Comment: Но придется писать под каждую единицу возраста?

Comment: Вы не чувствуете, что слово зависит от последней цифры? В крайнем случае, от последних двух?

Comment: Нет. Не нужно писать каждую единицу возраста. Вам код нужно упростить используя конструкции ИЛИ.

Comment: Можно дождаться красивого кода от кого-то... Но ведь вам намного приятнее будет прийти к такому коду самому. Задача вам по силам, вы сможете его не только "заставить" правильно работать, но и оптимизировать))

Comment: У вас цепочка `if`-ов, то есть проверки продолжаются даже после встречи с нужным условием. Замените все `if`, начиная со второго, на `else if`.

Comment: Да спасибо, потом понял, что так и стоит сделать, но перед этим я просто, поменял все условия наоборот, то есть начинал не с 0, а с максимального возраста 100, в итоге всё работает как нужно

Answer (score 4):

Что-то странное начинается в 51 год. Придется добавить в функцию еще кода (.

```js
function ageToText(years) {
  if (years == 0) {
    age = "";
  } else if (years == 1) {
    age = "год";
  } else if (years <= 4) {
    age = "года";
  } else if (years <= 20) {
    age = "лет";
  } else if (years == 21) {
    age = "год";
  } else if (years <= 24) {
    age = "года";
  } else if (years <= 30) {
    age = "лет";
  } else if (years == 31) {
    age = "год";
  } else if (years <= 34) {
    age = "года";
  } else if (years <= 40) {
    age = "лет";
  } else if (years == 41) {
    age = "год";
  } else if (years <= 44) {
    age = "года";
  } else if (years <= 50) {
    age = "лет";
  }
  return years + " " + age;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
  $("#ages").append(ageToText(i) + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ages"></div>
```

А вот как надо:

```js
function ageToText(years) {
  if (years == 0)
    return "";
    
  var age = "лет";  
  var last1 = years % 10;
  var last2 = years % 100;
  
  if (last2 >= 5 && last2 <= 20) {
    //age = "лет";
  } else if (last1 == 1) {
    age = "год";
  } else if (last1 >= 2 && last1 <= 4) {
    age = "года";
  }

  return years + " " + age;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 130; i++) {
  $("#ages").append(ageToText(i) + "<br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ages"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Моё виденье данного кода :

```
int lastNumberOfYear = years;
lastNumberOfYear %= 10;
if (lastNumberOfYear == 0 || lastNumberOfYear == 5 || lastNumberOfYear == 6 || lastNumberOfYear == 7 || lastNumberOfYear == 8 || lastNumberOfYear == 9) {
    age = "лет";
}
if (lastNumberOfYear == 1) {
    age = "год";
}
if (lastNumberOfYear == 2 || lastNumberOfYear == 3 || lastNumberOfYear == 4) {
    age = "года";
}
System.out.println(age + " " + years);
```

Comment: Ваше виденье не видит тинейджеров и некоторых долгожителей.

Comment: Действительно. На 11, 12, 13, 14, неверно. Стоит и первый digit учитывать.

Comment: Долгожителей с такими же числами: 11, 12, 13, 14, .... 111, 112, 113, 114, ... .

Answer (score 0):

Для меня ваши коды просто ломают голову, я сделал самым примитивным способом, но к сожалению это не цикл, а просто возраст от 0 до 100.
И я понял что оптимизация это не мой конёк :-)

```
String error = "Ошибка возраста";


    if (years <=100){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=94){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years <=91){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=90){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=84){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==81){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=80){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=74){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==71){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=70){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=64){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==61){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=60){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=54){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==51){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=60){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=54){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years <=50){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=44){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==41){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=40){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=34){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==31){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=30){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=24){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years ==21){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years <=20){
        age = "лет"; }
    if (years <=4){
        age = "года"; }
    if (years == 1 ){
        age = "год"; }
    if (years == 0 ){
        age = error; }
```

Comment: т.е. "101 год" или "102 года" уже не судьба? Вам же дали правильную рекомендацию "вычислять" по последней цифре. А если в дальнейшем вам потребуется сумму прописью сделать так же поступите?

Comment: Я еще слишком глуп для ваших кодов ,так то я понимаю, но что делает процент в коде?

Comment: @FussionBart Оператор `%` (`a % b`) вычисляет остаток от деления `a` на `b`.